# ActiveRecord (Rails 2.3.8) - Update existing, add new record when updating nested attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a "user" model that "has_one" "membership" (active at a time). For auditing and data integrity reasons, I'd like it so that if the membership changes for a user, the old/current record (if existing) has an inactive/active flag swapped, and a new row is added for the new changed record. If there are no changes to the membership, I'd like to just ignore the update. I've tried implementing this with a "before_save" call-back on my user model, but have failed many times. Any help is greatly appreciated.

models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :membership, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :membership, :allow_destroy => true  
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope :conditions => {:active => 1}
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working. While it's probably not the best implementation, all my tests are passing. Thanks for the input guys.

---

```
  before_save :soft_delete_changed_membership

  def soft_delete_changed_membership
    if !membership.nil? then
      if !membership.new_record? && membership.trial_expire_at_changed? then
        Membership.update_all( "active = 0", [ "id = ?", self.membership.id ] )
        trial_expire_at = self.membership.trial_expire_at
        self.membership = nil
        Membership.create!( 
          :user_id => self.id, 
          :trial_expire_at => trial_expire_at, 
          :active => true 
        )
        self.reload
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

I have what I think is a pretty elegant solution.  Here's your user model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :membership, :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :membership

  def update_membership_with_history attributes
    self.membership.attributes = attributes
    return true unless self.membership.changed?

    self.membership.update_attribute(:active, false)
    self.build_membership attributes

    self.membership.save
  end
end
```

This update_membership_with_history method allows us to handle changed or unchanged records.  Next the membership model:

```
class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope :conditions => {:active => true}
  belongs_to :user
end
```

I changed this slightly, since active should be a boolean, not 1's and 0's.  Update your migration to match.  Now the update action, which is the only part of your scaffold that needs to change:

```
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id], :include => :membership)
    membership_attributes = params[:user].delete(:membership_attributes)

    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user]) && @user.update_membership_with_history(membership_attributes)
      redirect_to users_path
    else
      render :action => :edit
    end
  end
```

We're simply parsing out the membership attributes (so you can still use fields_for in your view) and updating them separately, and only if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at [acts_as_versioned](http://github.com/technoweenie/acts_as_versioned)? In the `before_save` of the `Membership` you could create a new version of the `User`, which would be `acts_as_versioned`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just assume that the latest membership is the active one. This would save you a  lot of headache.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :memberships, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Membership < ActiveRecord::Base
  nested_scope :active, :order => "created_at DESC", :limit => 1
  belongs_to :user

  def update(attributes)
    self.class.create attributes if changed?
  end
end
```

then you can use

```
@user.memberships.active
```

to get the active membership, and you can just update any membership to get a new membership, which will become the active membership because it is the latest.

Comment: Thanks Edgerunner, but wouldn't that create a new record for every update to the user model if updated through a nested form where the membership fields were referenced (fields_for)?

Comment: That's correct, but simple to fix. Just add `if changed?`. Updating answer now.

Comment: Edgerunner, I couldn't get it to work with arguments being passed to update, kept getting errors as if the method didn't support the signature being used (1 for 0). I did however get it working with the following: 


def update
    if changed? then
      self.class.update_all( 'deleted_at = now()', [ "id = ?", self.id ] )
      self.class.create( self.attributes ) 
    end
 end

Comment: `self.class.update_all` sounds dangerous. It probably will not respect associations